# Getting more information about PH brand transistor manufacturer

Tags: identification

I have several transistors marked as:

```
PH
331XN
m9249
```

The package is SOT-82 and here is the photo:
[image]

But can not find any information about the brand **PH**...
Some says it is equivalent of BD331 transistor. Perhaps "PH" is abbreviation for PHILIPS?

Comment: Perhaps- the date code would indicate that they are 25 years old. But maybe they are more recent product by some Chinese maker who wants you to think of Philips, since the XN suffix does not seem to be Philips or NXP.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's a Philips BD331XN darlington transistor and the datasheet is [here](http://pdf1.alldatasheet.com/datasheet-pdf/view/123384/PHILIPS/BD331.html).

Comment: I suggest there is no chances to know what does the "XN" letters mean? Datasheet does not contain such information.

Comment: @ErnestasGruodis I don't know what "XN" suffix means and, as you said, datasheet does not contain any labeling info. But I'm sure it is a BD331. Also, this question is asked in a [forum thread on a German page](http://www.repdata.de/wbb2/index.php?page=Thread&threadID=32190) and one of the 5-star members suggested that the transistor is a BD331.